# ... should not be highlightable or clickable

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The **...** in the number of pages for the jobs feature should not be highlightable or clickable just as it is not in stackoverflow.  If I hover over it in SO it works as expected, however, hovering over it in the jobs feature looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the report, Jon! This is fixed on prod.